# Disable form submission button - InnerHTML (Security Risk) and CSS Style (Re-entering)

Tags: javascript

I have created a button that hopefully only allows submission once it has been clicked ([here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALxkRK) the code).

1. Does using `InnerHTML` present a security risk? (I watched on an
   online course that `InnerHTML` was to be avoided)
2. When I disable the pointers/cursors it seems to reset the buttons `CSS` and I have to re-enter the `inline CSS` for the button in `Javascript` again. Why is this?

   Results

   ```
    function change_button() {
   document.getElementById('get-results').innerHTML = 'Processing....';
   document.getElementById('get-results').style.cssText = 'pointer-events:none !important;cursor:not-allowed !important; height: 44px; color:#fff; font-size:18px; padding: 9px 20px; background-color: #000; display:inline-block; padding-right: 20px;'
   }
   ```

Comment: For number 2, it's because you're setting the whole CSS of that element to just the pointer events (you added the extra stuff back in in this example, though). Without the extra stuff, that line would do this: {color:#334466;width:12px;} --> {pointer-events:none;} since it would overwrite the whole CSS style object with that one set of CSS rules.

Comment: So is it possible to add new pointer events/cursor CSS in JS without resetting the buttons style? Please fork and show on Codepen if this is indeed possible.

Comment: Yes you can. Use element.style.backgroundColor = '#334466'; Substitute the property you need. See: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/setting_css_styles_using_javascript.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better just to set the button to disabled, which should prevent further clicks, and you won't need to mess about with your CSS either. As the comments mention, your current code wipes out the existing styles applied to the button.

However, I would still implement a server-side mechanism to prevent double processing of your submitted data, as there could be other ways that a duplicate submission could occur such as a browser refresh.

As far as security risks related to using innerHTML, I'm not aware of any in this case... Can you elaborate on what risks concern you?

By the way, passing a reference to 'this' in your onclick gives you an easy way to reference the clicked button without having to use getElementById.

```js
function change_button(btn) {
  btn.disabled = true;
  btn.innerHTML = "Processing...";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="change_button(this);" style="cursor: pointer; height: 44px; color:#fff; font-size:18px; padding: 9px 20px; background-color: #000; display:inline-block; padding-right: 20px;" id="get-results">Results</button>
```

Comment: Is InnerHTML ok to use then? No security risks or anything (Or is it only risky when there is client side input. eg. Somebody enter something into a input field etc)

Comment: I can't see how there could be any security risk associated with replacing the innerHTML with simple string constant ("Processing..."). I'm sure there _could_ be security implications if the content contained markup/script and/or was taken from user input. This applies anywhere that type of content is used however, it's not particularly related to the innerHTML property.